# Does gcc have any options to add version info in ELF binary file?

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

I mean whether gcc can insert some source code version infor into ELF binary as section or something similar.  I do not want to change my source file, but add some info with gcc option in Makefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can emit your version info into a text file, then turn that text file into an object file which you then statically link into your executable.

The first step is simple but you have to write some code: a script or something to write your version info in any format you like as a plain text file.  Then write a makefile rule to produce say version.o from version.txt, using [objcopy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy).  Now you'll have an object file with two useful symbols defined in it: the beginning and end of the textual version info.  Add that generated object to your executable, and you'll be able to access the version two ways: by running `strings` on the binary, or by writing code in the application to print the version string (you'll need to declare the start and end symbols as variables in some header file).

Comment: Thanks. I find that there is better method wiith objcopy: objcopy --add-section versection=version_text main main_version. And with "objdump -s -j versection main_version", the version can be retrieved.

Comment: Hi John, I see you're active member, even if this answer is old. Do you care to update it with some very basic/simple example of how to compile a text file to an object? Say "version 1.1.1" or something. This is exact the question I was going to make, and, well, it would be a (more/less) "duplicate"...

Comment: @DrBeco: on Linux you can use `objcopy` with the `--input binary` and `--output` formats explicitly specified.  There is a full tutorial on this here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967 .  You can also use `ld` with some options, I think `-b` to do about the same thing, perhaps even easier depending on your exact scenario.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind changing your source file just once, add something like this:

```
const volatile static char version[] = VERSION;
```

and compile with:

```
gcc -c -DVERSION='"1.2.3"'
```

The `volatile` keeps gcc from removing the string at higher optimization levels.

As written, this won't compile if you forget the `-D` option, which may be either good or bad depending on your requirements.

Comment: how do you read this version code from Linux command line or bash script? Thanks

Comment: @George There's no straightforward way to do that. The `version` string should be *somewhere* in the executable file, but you don't know where. One possibility is to add some unique string that can be searched for (but that assumes that string doesn't happen to appear elsewhere).

Answer (score 7):

Even if you don't have access to your source anymore, you can link the object with this option:

```
gcc -Wl,--defsym,VERSION_1_2_3=0 prog.o -o prog
```

You can check it with `hexdump -C prog | less` and look for `VERSION`

---

Add this to your `makefile` and be sure to always know when a program was compiled:

```
BUILD = $(shell date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
LDLIBS = -Wl,--defsym,BUILD_$(BUILD)=0
```

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU linker ld You can use

```
--version-script=version-scriptfile
```

Read more about the command-line options at:
[Using LD, the GNU linker - Options](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html)

Read more about creating version scripts at:
[Using LD, the GNU linker - Version Script](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html#SEC25)

Let me warn you though, that it is not for the weak-hearted!

Comment: Version scripts are intended for different purposes than just recording compiler settings.