# Interaction between the optimizer and strings dedicated to the what command

Tags: c++, c

the command "what" is used on my project to query some peaces of informations about executables (compilation date, version, ...).
I am fixing a bug where one line is missing in what output since we have changed the version of gcc. The string was defined in a local scope:

```
char string_for_what = "@(#) Component comp1";
```

This string was never used. I assume the optimizer has removed it.

I think the normal correction should be to declare the string at a global scope. But what prohibits a future compiler to optimize it away if it is not used ?

I have thought about calling `strlen("@(#) Component comp1")` to ensure that the string is used, but it seems that clang is optimizing away this call on constant strings.

Shoud I call `fopen("@(#) Component comp1")` ? If someone creates a file with this name, I may lose one file descriptor. This seems to work but it seems also a bit overkill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349557/does-gcc-have-any-options-to-add-version-info-in-elf-binary-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this declaration to a global scope may easily lead to violation of [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

You can prohibit optimizing out these variables using `volatile` keyword.

> `[C++11: 3.7.3:]` If a variable with automatic storage duration has initialization or a
>   destructor with side effects, it shall not be destroyed before the end
>   of its block, nor shall it be eliminated as an optimization even if it
>   appears to be unused, (...)

and:

> `[C++11: 1.9.12:]` Accessing an object designated by a volatile glvalue (3.10), modifying
>   an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that
>   does any of those operations are all side effects

Comment: Do you advise volatile char string_for_what[] = "@(#) Component comp1"; or volatile string string_for_what("@(#) Component comp1"); ? Thank you very much

Comment: @BOC I'd use a char array.