# Any way to set version of a binary built with g++?

Tags: c++, g++

Is there any way you can set the version number of a binary built with g++ on Linux? I know on Windows this is quite easy in the project settings of Visual Studio but can you do it on Linux? I'm using eclipse as my IDE.

Comment: What's the version number of a binary built?

Comment: I mean the file version number

Comment: There's no such thing like a _"file vwrsion number"_ unless you introduce some repository database like SVN or such.

Comment: Do you mean the `soname` (including version) of a shared library?   A generic ELF executable does not contain any standardized "version number" of the executable AFAIK. But, you can embed whatever info you like in a custom ELF header or section, for *your own* use - just don't expect anyone else to pay it any attention.

Comment: Back in the day, people used the `rcs` versioning system and put strings in each `.c` file, like `static char const rcsid[] = "$Id: f.c,v 5.4 1993/11/09 17:40:15 eggert Exp $";`. These strings could later be extracted with `ident binary` to get a list of all the object files used to build the binary. I think that practise stopped last millennia.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as ELF file version in Linux environment but this answer can help you to make workaround about it [Does gcc have any options to add version info in ELF binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349557/does-gcc-have-any-options-to-add-version-info-in-elf-binary-file)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like a lot of hassle for something small. I think it might be easier if the program outputs the version when you run with a '--version' flag. Ideally I shouldn't have to run the program at all.